# Java 17 JDK Install exe won't run

Tags: java, windows-10, access-violation

I am trying to download Java 17, but whenever I run the jdk-java17.exe file, nothing happens, this occurs when run as administrator as well. When I debug the exe in Visual Studio, I get this error message:

```
The thread 0x13e8 has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
The thread 0x44f0 has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
The thread 0x424c has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
The program '[10912] jdk-17.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I have no idea if this has anything to do with the issue, but my computer has also been shutting down while asleep and has been having audio problems recently (crackling, audio gets ahead of video by a lot, etc.). Any insight on the problem helps.

Thank you!

Comment: When run, the MSI file just returns that it failed, saying that the wizard was interrupted before it could be completely installed.

Comment: Start with turning it completely off and on again

Comment: Thank you, but I have probably done that every 3 hours for a week or 2. It is the only way to reset the audio problem. Restarting hasn't helped this issue.

Comment: Then your windows installation may be broken. First verify that your hardware is ok.  Memtest86 (create a bootable usb on another computer) is a good way to test your ram.

Comment: What are the consequences and requirements of doing that? Would I lose my personal files (including programs and program files)? Do I need a very large USB?

Comment: My advice will be: please, do not use the .msi, it basically uncompress and in include the location in which the contents were uncompressed in your `PATH` variable. Please, instead, consider [download the .zip version file from OpenJDK](https://adoptium.net/releases.html), for example, uncompress the archive where your consider ir appropriate and include the `bin` folder in your `PATH` variable or configure your IDE to use that JDK.

Comment: @jccampanero That depends. Typically, if I were to do it manually, I would end up just doing what the installer would have done anyway--at least on my personal computers.

Comment: I agree with you @Slaw, at a first glance the installer should be totally fine. In my comment I wanted to mean that sometimes the installer gives some problems like here, and perhaps  downloading the zip file and uncompressing it would be the only steps necessary to successfully install the SDK, so this alternative step could be worth value.

Comment: @palikai your machine sounds very Sick.  You should fix that first of all .  If you don’t have a backup and fear losing your files now might be a good time to consider.

Comment: Is there a way to save all of my files(everything) to my D: drive then reformat everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my SSD C-Drive was broken. Got a new one and all my problems were solved!